# permutations of vectors in matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, permutation

I have a static matrix from a file:

```
    size(data)=[80 5]
```

What I want is to change position of each vector randomly 
when I use perms like:

```
    N = size(data, 1);
    X = perms(1:N);                    % # Permutations of column indices
    Y = meshgrid(1:N, 1:factorial(N)); % # Row indices
    idx = (X - 1) * N + Y;             % # Convert to linear indexing
    C = data(idx)
```

But its giving me an error: `Maximum variable size allowed by the program is
exceeded.`
Is there any other function to give me what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think im done

```
 N = size(data, 1);
 r=randperm(N);
 for ii=1:80
   matrix(r(ii),:) =data(ii,:)  ;     
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

`perms` is not good for large numbers i.e any number >10

Refer the [Documentation](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html)

It says

> perms(v) is practical when length(v) is less than about 10.

See the size it takes from the following code:

```
MB(10,1) = 0;
for N = 1:10
    X = perms(1:N);
    dt=whos('X');
    MB(N)=dt.bytes*9.53674e-7;
end

plot(1:10,MB,'r*-');
```

Note the sudden rise in the steepness of the curve beyond 9.

[image]

Comment: @binar, y do u need all of them? if you mention some more details, somebody here, might put an alternative.

Comment: its pocket algorithm, i need each vector to learn the perceptron.
i found the answer :

      N = size(data, 1);
      r=randperm(N);
      for ii=1:80
       matrix(r(ii),:) =data(ii,:)  ;     
      end

Comment: @binar Glad you found the answer. Kindly post it as an answer and Accept it. It means to tell the system that you no longer need help for this problem :)